# ¿Cuál es la función de las anotaciones en Java?

Tags: java, annotation

Estoy viendo el tema de las anotaciones en la [documentación de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html). Y viendo este ejemplo :

```
@ClassPreamble (
   author = "John Doe",
   date = "3/17/2002",
   currentRevision = 6,
   lastModified = "4/12/2004",
   lastModifiedBy = "Jane Doe",
   // Note array notation
   reviewers = {"Alice", "Bob", "Cindy"}
)
public class Generation3List extends Generation2List {

// class code goes here

}
```

no entiendo aún para qué me puede servir. Por ejemplo, si le quito la anotación sigue funcionando; entonces, ¿para qué sirven generalmente? Me explicaron que sirven para las interfaces pero hasta ahí entendí.

Comment: basicamente las anotaciones se usan para que el contendor se encargue de alguna tarea, como por ejemplo proveer instancias de alguna dependencia, etc.

Comment: No tiene por qué ser el contenedor: puede ser el compilador, una librería que estás usando o tu propio código el que haga uso de las anotaciones

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interesante pregunta en la cual quiero aportar mi granito de arena.

### ¿Qué son las @notaciones?

Las [anotaciones](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) son una forma de metadatos que proporcionan datos sobre un programa que no forma parte del programa en sí. Las anotaciones no tienen ningún efecto directo en el funcionamiento del código que anotan.

Las anotaciones tienen una serie de usos, entre ellos:

- **Información para el compilador**: El compilador puede utilizar las anotaciones para detectar errores o suprimir las advertencias.
- **Procesamiento en tiempo de compilación y tiempo de implementación**: Las herramientas de software pueden procesar información de anotaciones para generar código, archivos XML, etc.
- **Procesamiento de tiempo de ejecución:** algunas anotaciones están disponibles para ser examinadas en tiempo de ejecución.

### Conceptos básicos sobre anotaciones

### *El formato de una anotación*

En su forma más simple, una anotación se parece a la siguiente:

```
@Entidad
```

El carácter de signo (`@`) indica al compilador que lo que sigue es una anotación. En el siguiente ejemplo, el nombre de la anotación es `Override`:

```
@Override
void mySuperMethod() { ... }
```

La anotación puede incluir *elementos*, que pueden ser nombrados o sin nombre, y hay valores para esos elementos:

```
@Author(
   name = "Benjamin Franklin",
   date = "3/27/2003"
)
class MyClass() { ... }
or

@SuppressWarnings(value = "unchecked")
void myMethod() { ... }
```

Si sólo hay un elemento denominado valor, el nombre puede omitirse, como en:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
void myMethod() { ... }
```

Si la anotación no tiene elementos, los paréntesis se pueden omitir, como se muestra en el ejemplo anterior de `@Override`.

También es posible utilizar múltiples anotaciones en la misma declaración:

```
@Author(name = "Jane Doe")
@EBook
class MyClass { ... }
```

Si las anotaciones tienen el mismo tipo, entonces se denomina anotación repetitiva:

```
@Author(name = "Jane Doe")
@Author(name = "John Smith")
class MyClass { ... }
```

Las anotaciones repetidas se admiten desde la versión de Java SE 8. Para obtener más información, consulte [Anotaciones repetidas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html).

El tipo de anotación puede ser uno de los tipos que se definen en los paquetes `java.lang` o `java.lang.annotation` de la API de Java SE. En los ejemplos anteriores, `Override` y `SuppressWarnings` son anotaciones Java predefinidas. También es posible definir su propio tipo de anotación. Las anotaciones de `Author` y `Ebook` en el ejemplo anterior son tipos de anotaciones personalizadas.

### ¿Dónde puedo utilizar anotaciones?

Las anotaciones se pueden aplicar a declaraciones: declaraciones de clases, campos, métodos y otros elementos del programa. Cuando se utiliza en una declaración, cada anotación suele aparecer, por convención, en su propia línea.

A partir de la versión Java SE 8, las anotaciones también se pueden aplicar al uso de tipos. Aquí hay unos ejemplos:

- Expresión de creación de instancia de clase:

  `new @Interned MyObject();`
- Tipo emitido:

  `MyString = (cadena @NonNull) str;`
- cláusula `implements`:

  `class UnmodifiableList<T> implements
          @Readonly List<@Readonly T> { ... }`
- Declaración de excepción lanzada:

  `void monitorTemperature() throws
          @Critical TemperatureException { ... }`

  Esta forma de anotación se llama *anotación de tipo*. Para obtener más información, consulte [Anotaciones de tipo y sistemas de tipo conectable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html).

### Declaración de un tipo de anotación

Muchas anotaciones reemplazan los comentarios en el código.

Supongamos que un grupo de software tradicionalmente comienza el cuerpo de cada clase con comentarios que proporcionan información importante:

```
public class Generation3List extends Generation2List {

   // Author: John Doe
   // Date: 3/17/2002
   // Current revision: 6
   // Last modified: 4/12/2004
   // By: Jane Doe
   // Reviewers: Alice, Bill, Cindy

   // class code goes here

}
```

Para agregar estos mismos metadatos con una anotación, primero debe definir el tipo de anotación. La sintaxis para hacer esto es:

```
@interface ClassPreamble {
   String author();
   String date();
   int currentRevision() default 1;
   String lastModified() default "N/A";
   String lastModifiedBy() default "N/A";
   // Note use of array
   String[] reviewers();
}
```

La definición de tipo de anotación es similar a una definición de interfaz en la que la interfaz de palabras clave está precedida por el signo at (@) (@ = AT, como en el tipo de anotación). Los tipos de anotación son una forma de interfaz, que se tratará en una lección posterior. Por el momento, no es necesario entender las interfaces.

El cuerpo de la definición de anotación anterior contiene declaraciones de elementos de tipo de anotación, que se parecen mucho a los métodos. Tenga en cuenta que pueden definir valores opcionales por defecto.

Una vez definido el tipo de anotación, puede utilizar anotaciones de ese tipo, con los valores rellenados, de la siguiente manera:

```
@ClassPreamble (
   author = "John Doe",
   date = "3/17/2002",
   currentRevision = 6,
   lastModified = "4/12/2004",
   lastModifiedBy = "Jane Doe",
   // Note array notation
   reviewers = {"Alice", "Bob", "Cindy"}
)
public class Generation3List extends Generation2List {

// class code goes here

}
```

---

**Nota:** Para que la información en `@ClassPreamble` aparezca en la documentación generada por Javadoc, debe anotar la definición de `@ClassPreamble` con la anotación `@Documented`:

```
// import this to use @Documented
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Documented
@interface ClassPreamble {

   // Annotation element definitions

}
```

### Y... hay más

Si quieres realizar un *doctorado* en @notaciones, dejo estos enlaces que completan el tutorial de la doc de Java:

- [Predefined Annotation Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html)
- [Type Annotations and Pluggable Type Systems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html)
- [Repeating Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html)
- [Questions and Exercises: Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/QandE/questions.html) o Exámen final para optar por el doctorado :)

Answer (score -1):

Yo tambien tenía mis dudas sobre las annotations hasta que leí esta pulicación de MEDIUM muy fácil y muy bien explicada https://medium.com/@alvareztech/java-annotations-b8ae69739b4e. Espero que les sea de utilidad.

Te pongo un ejemplo de una annotations muy utilizada, el @override le dice al compilador que sobrescriba el método de la clase padre, por supuesto esto es cuando hay herencias de clases.